# How do I ask a user continuously input something?

Tags: python

I wrote a program that has a user input a word to produce a list of anagrams. How do I have it so that I can keep asking the user to input something until they input a blank line?

Comment: Use a loop, perhaps?

Comment: while true ask input , if input is bye then quit

Comment: Simplest way to achieve this would be using loops. Otherwise, there some hard ways like calling/texting user asking him to enter inputs multiple times.

Comment: You can literally google "python continuous user input" and find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546761/python-continuously-prompting-for-user-input). Is google harder than asking here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while(True):
    x = raw_input("Enter something:")
    if x == "":
        break
```

Essentially, this will continue to ask the user `Enter something:` until the user enters nothing. If you want to parse the input into numbers, then you will need to have a `try:...except:...` in your code, or else it will break.

Comment: Please don't cater to questions with no effort. We have standards here.

Comment: Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: Helping is fine, but helping on a question that a 5 second google search answers isn't what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Understood.